# Facebook's control over application's datas

Tags: facebook, policy

I would like to developp an application, that would connect companies and clients together. However, information that would result of such interactions, need to be confidential. I don't want facebook to use this information for it's own use, or sell it to a third part. Would facebook have control over such datas? I hope my question is clear enough, and i'm looking forward to your answers

(sorry for my english, i'm not english native speaker)

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, if you're dealing with confidential data do not involve storing it on Facebook at **ANY** stage of the process.

Comment: So, if i simply use facebook platform to create my app, and don't store any datas on facebook, it doesn't have any control over anything?! The app can be totally independant?!

Comment: @CecileAix If you don't store any actual data on Facebook, then you'll be fine. However, if you're using a Facebook app to set up the initial contact, then yes, Facebook will have a record of that connection and the data exchanged using it. They will be able to match up any data the two parties have already entered into their Facebook accounts (whether they make use of that data is a different matter!).

Comment: what do you mean by "if you're using a Facebook app to set up the initial contact"?

Comment: If you're just using it to introduce two parties and they then conduct their confidential business outside of your app, then all Facebook can access is that initial interaction and no more. If they then continue to communiate through your app, then Facebook can potentially log such data.

Answer (score 0):

what @Widor said is very true.  You can have as much connectivity between clients, companies across applications or whatever else you want to with out involving facebook in the transactions themselves.  You can integrate facebook only as a login process and once you have verified the user your app can do whatever it wants and facebok will not know of it. (unless you are dealing with data taken from facebook)